# difficulties Mapping maps with hibernate using JPA annotations

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dictionary, annotations, mapping

There is possibly something fundamental I don't understand about the semantics of JPA @MapKey element. 
I am trying to save a Map that has entity keys and entity values. The Schema is auto 
generated by hibernate. It generates a join table that maps the values entities to 
the containing entity (that has the Map property) and ignores the keys. 
so effectively it just treats it as a collection of values and ignores the keys, 
as far as I can tell. 
what am i missing here ? 
Thank you

```
@Entity
public class PracticeMap {
    @javax.persistence.OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @javax.persistence.MapKey 
    public Map<KeySample, ValueSample> getMap1() {
        return map1;
    }

    //more unrelated/standard bits here 


}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [javadoc of `@MapKey`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKey.html) - it's used when you need to treat particular fields of the value entity as keys.

If your key and value should be different entities, you need to use [`@MapKeyJoinColumn`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyJoinColumn.html) (introduced in JPA 2.0).